# How can I retrieve more than 50 Autoscaling Groups via Python Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, autoscaling, aws-sdk

Hello and thanks in advance for any help...

I am trying to use boto to retrieve a list of all Autoscaling groups in my account. I have 164 Autoscaling Groups but the boto script is only retrieving the first 50 in similar fashion to the console.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from boto.ec2.autoscale import AutoScaleConnection
    conn = AutoScaleConnection('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS', 'TUVWXYZ/ABCDEFGHIJKLMN')

    agroups = conn.get_all_groups()
    print agroups
```

Any ideas as to how I can pull the entire list of my AS groups?

Answer (score 2):

Boto does not automatically handle the paging of results from the `DescribeAutoScalingGroups` API call like it does for many other calls.  So you have to handle the paging yourself.

```
import boto.ec2.autoscale
c = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('us-east-1')  # or whatever region you want
all_groups = []
rs = c.get_all_groups()
all_groups.extend(rs)
while rs.next_token:
    rs = c.get_all_groups(next_token=rs.next_token)
    all_groups.extend(rs)
```

At the end of the loop, `all_groups` should contain all of the AutoScaling groups.  You can probably come up with a more elegant way of doing that but that should work and gives you the basic info about how to do paging.